# How can I see a list of all pages my WordPress site has generated?

Tags: permalinks, pages, links, sitemap

I would like to be able to to see some sort of list of all the individual pages my WordPress site has generated that would inevitably be visible to a user or a search engine. For example, I know tags and categories and even some plugins generate new types of pages many may be unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) to get a list of all pages that are linked to on your site. It doesn't technically show all pages that exist, but it shows all pages that a user or search engine could reasonably reach (i.e. those that are linked to from within your site).